# How do I obtain the value from first the row of a grouped part?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have products, invoices and clients. On the client invoice is a product with a selling price without tax. I need to report for each client, for `product_id =45`, the lowest selling price and also a selling price from the very first invoice.

I can group everything except the last condition. I know it can be done with a `subselect`, but I'd like to avoid them.

Simplified database structure:

```
table clients
-clent_id serial

table products
-product_id serial
-name text

table invoices
-invoice_id serial
-client_id int

table invoices_rows
-invoice_row_id serial
-invoice_id int
-product_id int
-price double precision
```

Comment: How is your current query failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) in combination with DISTINCT to get the lowest and the first price at the same time (without subselect as requested):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (i.client_id)
       i.client_id
     , min(ir.price) OVER (PARTITION BY i.client_id) AS min_price
     , first_value(ir.price) OVER (PARTITION BY i.client_id
                                   ORDER BY ir.invoice_id) AS first_price
FROM   invoices_rows ir
JOIN   invoices i USING (client_id)
WHERE  ir.product_id = 45;
```

Apply `DISTINCT ON` (client_id) to get just one row per `client_id`. DISTINCT is applied after window functions, while `GROUP BY` would be applied before.

I am assuming that "first invoice" can be interpreted as "lowest `invoice_id`".
Do you need "lowest selling price" for each client? Or the overall lowest price for the product? I changed to "per client_id" now. Seems more likely.

---

If you would not mind a subselect or CTE, this would probably perform best:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT i.client_id
         , min(ir.price) AS min_price
         , min(ir.invoice_id) AS invoice_id
    FROM   invoices_rows ir
    JOIN   invoices i USING (client_id)
    WHERE  ir.product_id = 45
    )
SELECT x.*, ir.price AS first_price
FROM   x
JOIN   invoices_rows ir USING (invoice_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that to get the selling price from the very first invoice you would need information on sale_date or a valid criteria that you didn't explain in your request.

There are different ways to achieve that result, but the one I prefer is based only on aggregate functions. The following sample uses [postges](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) but also other DB may give you the same functionality.

```
postgres=# select *
postgres-# from prices_products;
 product_name | customer_name | price | sell_date
--------------+---------------+-------+------------
 knife        | mark          |   100 | 2011-01-20
 book         | cris          |    20 | 2011-05-12
 book         | mark          |    25 | 2010-09-30
 book         | cris          |    30 | 2012-02-15
(4 rows)


postgres=#
postgres=# select product_name, customer_name,m as maximum, arr[1] as first_date_val
postgres-# from (
postgres(#              select product_name, customer_name, max(price) as m, array_agg(price order by sell_date) as arr
postgres(#              from prices_products
postgres(#              group by product_name, customer_name
postgres(#      ) a;
 product_name | customer_name | maximum | first_date_val
--------------+---------------+---------+----------------
 book         | cris          |      30 |             20
 book         | mark          |      25 |             25
 knife        | mark          |     100 |            100
(3 rows)


postgres=#
```